# Why JMeter has feature to exclude HTML files?

Tags: http, soap, ftp, jmeter

I am new to JMeter and have created Test Plan using different Protocols like SOAP, HTTP, FTP and have got very familiar to it.

What I would like to know is, why would I need to exclude .html files? Why this feature is provided by JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excluding HTML files isn't something which makes sense in load testing world. JMeter has feature to exclude certain domains **from HTML files**, i.e. if the web page has embedded call to external banner, control, image or application which is totally external and doesn't belong to your test scope it makes sense to filter out this external stuff.

For more detailed explanation and example regular expressions see [Excluding Certain Domains from the Load Test](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/140841-excluding-certain-domains-from-the-load-test) guide.

Comment: Hey Dmitri, I just went through the link you posted and that's really helpful.

Comment: @Priyanka If an answer helped solve your question you can "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. Both you and the person who answered will gain some reputation for doing so